# Storing Class Arguments in a List

Tags: python, list, class, python-2.7, arguments

Recently I've been working on a text-based game as a personal project. No real reason, just for the heck of it. I'm usually pretty fluent in Python (I've completed the entirety of CodeCademy's Python course and done my own research), but I've come across something that I want to make sure will work before implementing.

Essentially, is it possible to nest the arguments for a class into a list?

Here's an example similar to what I'm doing:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
         self.name = name
         self.weight = weight

tempDict = {
     'flashlight' = ['flashlight',5],
}

flashlight1 = Item(tempDict['flashlight'])

print flashlight1.name
```

That should return with:

```
flashlight
```

I'm really hoping this will work. I have an entire ID structure that relies on this working. If not, how can I do something similar so I can have a prescribed list of items and base values that I can assign to specific items with IDs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) `tempDict['flashlight']` by placing `*` in front of it:

```
>>> class Item(object):
...     def __init__(self, name, weight):
...          self.name = name
...          self.weight = weight
...
>>> tempDict = {
...      'flashlight' : ['flashlight',5],
... }
>>> flashlight1 = Item(*tempDict['flashlight'])
>>> print flashlight1.name
flashlight
>>> print flashlight1.weight
5
>>>
```

In the above demonstration:

```
flashlight1 = Item(*tempDict['flashlight'])
```

is equivalent to:

```
flashlight1 = Item('flashlight', 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary of arguments would be even clearer if you used dictionaries, rather than lists, to store the arguments:

```
tempDict = {
    'flashlight': { 'name': 'flashlight', 'weight': 5 }
}
flashlight1 = Item(**tempDict['flashlight'])
```